Is there a good term for instructions that are presented in the wrong order?
I'm trying to document/comment on an error someone is making in their technical writing, and I don't want to give half a page of explanation. I thought I'd heard a writing term for it.
It's where someone puts important information for the reader after the point they need it
e.g., Many of us have seen the joke on TV when the hero is diffusing a trap:
Step 2: Cut the red wire, but first cut the blue wire or you will set off the trap...

Is there a "good"/"common" name for that kind of structure?
Out of sequence instructions? Negated instruction? Late Override?

Surely it doesn't take half a page to note These instructions are in the wrong order.? While it might take half a page to explain that the Latinate term instructionesmisorderum (I made that one up for you) means These instructions are out of order.

Oh, and to pick a nit, that joke comes when the hero is defusing a bomb rather than when he hero is diffusing a trap.

Oh, I know where the joke comes from, I didn't want to write the question in away that adds to any watch lists :-)

If you don't readily know that term, why do you assume your readers will understand what it means? Instead of obfuscating your writing with uncommon terminology, use plain English.
Also, your question describes a common tendency among inexperienced writers to try and use abstract words that have a "denser" meaning instead of concrete and descriptive phrases, thus making their writing difficult to penetrate and arduous to read.
As High Performance Mark has said in their comment, "presented in the wrong order" is clear and concise. It is pleasant to read and easy to understand. There is absolutely no reason to replace it with some technical term — except wanting to appear learned.

Part of what I'm doing here is trying to follow a pattern from the software development world of describing common structural errors (so called "anti-patterns") with an industry short hand (e.g.,  If I remind someone "you shouldn't used Magic Numbers", everyone on my team should, and if not it's a 1/2 hour discussion on why they are bad).
I presumed that this situation might be common enough it had name like "Splitting Infinitives", and in the Fu-Bar company style guide, you should avoid them. That presumption may be it self an anti-pattern :-)

Accepted, and off to boldly split infinitives that have never been split before

I haven't heard of a term for it, but I would call it a "belated instruction", like a belated "happy birthday" or belated "congratulations".
